# A more efficient way to check contents of json object and apply jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I currently have a ajax call sending data to a controller and retrieving json data back.

the values that come back look like this

```
{
    "old": "The Old Password field is required.",
    "new": "The New Password field is required.",
    "new_confirm": "The Confirm New Password field is required."
}
```

now if the any of the json string is empty i want to hide the warning.

so far i have the below but i want to know if there is a better way to loop through the data with creating mutiple if/else statments

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#changepassword').click(function () { // form submit button
        $.ajax({
            url: "auth/change_password", // php controller
            async: false,
            type: "POST",
            data: $("#change_password_form").serialize(), //pass all form data
            dataType:"json",
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.old == "") {
                    $("#old").hide(); // hide old password alert div
                }
                else {
                    $("#old").show(); // show warning div
                    $("#old").empty(); // empty previous warning contents
                    $("#old").append(data.old); // append json string
                };
                //$('#ajax-content-container').html(data);
            }
        })
    });
})
```

Comment: There is no reason to use `async: false,` and anyway, FYI, this is deprecated

Comment: is it? what is the correct way now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you basically want to do the same for all 3 properties? Just use a for...in loop then.

```
for(var prop in data){
    if(data[prop] == ""){
        $("#" + prop).hide();
    }else{
        $("#" + prop).show();
        $("#" + prop).empty();
        $("#" + prop).append(data[prop]);
};
```

Comment: `else` statement could even be simplified to: `$("#" + prop).html(data[prop]).show();`

Comment: true that's even better

Answer (score 0):

If all properties match the respective DOM elements' ids you can use a `for..in` loop:

```
for(var prop in data) 
{
    var element = $('#' + prop);

    if(obj[prop]){
        // There is error message -> Show it
        element.text(data[prop]).show();
    } else {
        // There isn't error message -> Hide it
        element.hide();            
    }
}
```